# How to detect the cause of the 'Element' is an invalid XmlNodeType error when using IClientMessageInspector?

Tags: xml, web-services, digital-signature

I am sending some data via a third party webservice. The data I am sending has to be signed first, so my plan is correctly set up SOAP message with XML inside it is following:

1. Construct the object I need to send to the web service.
2. Attach my instance of IClientMessageInspector to sign the deserialized object
3. Use XmlReader to add the signed xml into the message that is going to be sent to the webservice body
4. Send the message and profit :)

However this does not work out, because before sending the message to the web service the following exception is thrown : `'Element' is an invalid XmlNodeType`

Here is chunks of code that are used to create and sign the message:

Creating the object that the will be turned into a SOAP message:

```
Test.item ItemToSend = new Test.item();

ItemToSend.id = "uniqueNodeId";
ItemToSend.pid = "VSID000000000113";
ItemToSend.customData = "correlationData";
ItemToSend.postbackUrl = "does not matter";
ItemToSend.userInformation = new Test.userInformation[]
{
   Test.userInformation.id,
   Test.userInformation.firstName,
   Test.userInformation.lastName
};

ItemToSend.authenticationProvider = new Test.itemProvider[] 
{
   Test.itemProvider.authltidentitycard,
   Test.itemProvider.authltbank,
   Test.itemProvider.authsignatureProvider,
   Test.itemProvider.authltgovernmentemployeecard
};

ItemToSend.authenticationAttribute = new Test.itemAttribute[]
{
   Test.itemAttribute.ltpersonalcode,
   Test.itemAttribute.ltcompanycode
};
```

Code used to modify the SOAP message just before sending it to the web service:

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
{
   XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
   XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms);
   request.WriteMessage(writer);
   writer.Flush();
   ms.Position = 0;
   doc.Load(ms);
   SignDocument(doc, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_LocalResources/testCert.pem"), System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_LocalResources/testKey.pem"));
   //ChangeMessage(doc, true);
   ms.SetLength(0);
   writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms);
   doc.WriteTo(writer);
   writer.Flush();
   ms.Position = 0;
   XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(ms);
   request = Message.CreateMessage(reader, int.MaxValue, request.Version);
   return null;
}
```

The signed XML that is to be put into a SOAP message (the contents of the doc object):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none" s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.epaslaugos.lt/services/authenticationServiceProvider/initAuthentication</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <authenticationRequest xmlns="does not matter">
      <pid>VSID000000000113</pid>
      <serviceTarget>citizen</serviceTarget>
      <authenticationProvider>auth.lt.identity.card</authenticationProvider>
      <authenticationProvider>auth.lt.bank</authenticationProvider>
      <authenticationProvider>auth.signatureProvider</authenticationProvider>
      <authenticationProvider>auth.lt.government.employee.card</authenticationProvider>
      <authenticationAttribute>lt-personal-code</authenticationAttribute>
      <authenticationAttribute>lt-company-code</authenticationAttribute>
      <userInformation>id</userInformation>
      <userInformation>firstName</userInformation>
      <userInformation>lastName</userInformation>
      <postbackUrl>does not matter</postbackUrl>
      <customData>correlationData</customData>
      <id>uniqueNodeId</id>
    </authenticationRequest>
  </s:Body>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
        <InclusiveNamespaces xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="s"/>
      </CanonicalizationMethod>
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
      <Reference URI="">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
            <InclusiveNamespaces xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="s"/>
          </Transform>
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
        <DigestValue>vXs8k7faSipYtQ7AGsbP2yK0Nxo=</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>aPdWNziCci0F5/Qt+naKWqBjV9XVHyjk5YEX0tDXBOx4tbrh26bwl8DJuMULZ7RIXzxUQ8SD94T+Qsd1H83u7xCt8c1iWyMSJv0hSp2RIj3V+VyqnpkHJMIbZghUtRb11R7PeJTJEUtlS42PNRhCILtsfn7G65YCDtsNKhCL/8hqcJyg4/kBx9OFzJTga+1mXgIYusN8vlQdMog0CISNOxYn8MwG/XOlPbybyv3CjT2eethPZ6dFo8FE1qFkYq8txiSjxSaVlhxRedcWtiAf5r7LvXWvnYP85mZ86A3BHPT2/jq9hHtnNPzgvKJ3QrtHuY0lE5AuTnPIZBNKjkUnVQ==</SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo>
      <KeyValue>
        <RSAKeyValue>
          <Modulus>i+rh6NJ7Z6Q8XiMSVK/Z8DYXIyk5j7N9GUX8AOSKONabse4us7/ogR0x7OOf0FsrdxAhQls59Wn1vDxujSVOu3v1JhML/v/WK8glcxM433oEEpb0C56XRHlt27Qkbsn6v3njC1z0NGyDFdAtg5PaMx7YmjyWR6ezMKj9wR5cK4CRZ7idm2PwzQaLUDFm7wUFXudZNkQ6pb60OvDw4ey1t68EVCPtq4nGdHG+3jlSDTTJc/03qk50pa6Nb/t5+EWsE3jFt/uhHim1rC2pMf5UrT26FL6/DjA0PxQFecc76zeuv3xbGSP7B7ubpG8fyatGb4oLB4eU0ceCJvqljGMP0w==</Modulus>
          <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
        </RSAKeyValue>
      </KeyValue>
    </KeyInfo>
  </Signature>
</s:Envelope>
```

The most interesting part of this issue is that the method Message.CreateMessage() runs fine. The request object is generated, however, the exception is thrown just before sending the message to the web service.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that I was trying to sign the whol SOAP message, not the XML itself. Signing the XML solved the problem.